# access post files to nodejs without saving to disk

Tags: node.js

I'm using Heroku to store my Express app and I can't use bodyParser, or formidable, because both uses temp files to store the posted file.

The file I'm posting is simply a large text file (csv). I don't really need to store the file anywhere, because the data will go into mongodb.

Is there anyway to parse the csv file as it is being uploaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Connect 2.9.0 (Express 3.4.0), `bodyParser` uses [multiparty](https://github.com/superjoe30/node-multiparty) instead of formidable.

In multiparty's default configuration, **it does not create temporary files**.  Read the docs to see exactly how to handle the incoming data, but you'll want to listen to the `part` event, which gives you a readable stream containing the uploaded file.